# Efecto transición suave Menú Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un menú que me dirige a las secciones de mi página, pero lo hace muy rápido (instantáneo)
¿Cómo hago un efecto que vaya suavemente a las secciones con el menú de bootstrap? sin que haga el salto tan brusco.

En general era para hacer un efecto de animación suave para los links de "ancla" #.
la respuesta está al final.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo actual, asi es mas facil que te podamos ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Gracias @Fernando Forcén  Aquí está el script por si alguien necesita ahce justamente lo que quiero.

```
$(function(){

     $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
         && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

             var $target = $(this.hash);

             $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

             if ($target.length) {

                 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

                 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

                 return false;

            }

       }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando JQuery en tu página puedes usar el método `animate` para hacer el scroll de forma suave usando `scrollTop`. Aquí tienes la documentación: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para que veas el resultado: https://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/exByn